# jQuery + Not Selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Being a newbie to Javascript and jQuery, I am not sure whether this is not possible at all or I am just doing a completely dumb mistake:

I am trying to hide a `div` on any click outside the `div` itself.

I have simplified the code for demonstration purpose:

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <div class="tooltip">
        Bla Bla Bla
    </div>
</html>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('html:not(.tooltip)').click(function() {

    $('.tooltip').hide();

});
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/yCx6F/1/

Comment: I'm on my iPad so I can't be certain, but it looks like click is not binding to the HTML element. Try adding another div to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
$(document).click(function(ev) {
    if (!$(ev.target).is('.tooltip')) $('.tooltip').hide();
});
```

Comment: Works! So far yours and Bender´s answer seem to work - any suggestion which one I should choose? I am, as I said, a newbie and cant really decide which one is the "better" answer.

Comment: His solution is clear and works, so maybe you can pick up the one that was answered first or the one you feel more confortable with...

Comment: I chose yours, but just in case any1 else is reading this: I had to add the child elements (`.tooltip p` in my case) to the selector, because it kept closing when I clicked on the text instead of the surrounding div (`.tooltip`)!

Answer (score 5):

Add a space:

```
$('html :not(.tooltip)')
```

When you say `html:not(...)`, you are looking for all `html` elements not matching your selector.

Adding a space looks for children of the `html` element, which is what you want.

See if this does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/yCx6F/2/

---

Actually, you should be doing this:

```
$('.tooltip').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

// Once the `<div>` is created, in the same function:

$(document).one(function() {
  $('.tooltip').hide();
});
```

Comment: `.tooltip` still dissapears when clicking on it.

Comment: Since gustavotkg´s answer works too, I was wondering, if you could let me know what are the pros and cons (if there are any) to your and his way - that would help me to decide what to choose as answer!

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
$('*:not(.tooltip)').click(function() {
    $('.tooltip').hide();
});

$('.tooltip').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work! - But nevermind, since Blender´s answer did the trick.

Comment: You're right. I tried it in JSFiddle with an alert instead of the hide and it worked, but the hide didn't. I updated my answer just to make it correct and provide an alternative to Blender's answer. His answer looks fine to me, though if these are tooltips, I'm not sure you want to use the one() method (it will only work once).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a space.

```
$('html :not(.tooltip)').click(function() {

    $('.tooltip').hide();

});
```

---

```
$('html:not(.tooltip)').click(function() {
```

Means any HTML element which isn't .tooltip

```
$('html :not(.tooltip)').click(function() {
```

Means any element within HTML which isn't .tooltip

---

**[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/yCx6F/4/)**

Comment: See my comment to @Blender ´s answer. It still dissapears.